# Spotfire: changing formula in calc column using IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, spotfire

Long time user very first question:

I am trying to update the formula in a calculated column in Spotfire using ironpython. I have a table called tbl_test with calculated column 'Biz_rule'. I create a string called str_statement and try to use it to replace the expression in the caluclated column with the code below:

```
calc_col = tbl_test.Columns.Item['Biz_rule']
calc_col = calc_col.As<CalculatedColumn>()
calc_col.Expression = str_statement;
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Spotfire.Dxp.Application.ScriptSupport", line unknown, in ExecuteForDebugging
  File "<string>", line 25, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'Expression'
```

I assume because

```
calc_col.As<CalculatedColumn>()
```

returns a boolean indicating whether or not the operation succeeded. How do I get an instance of the calculated column so I can update the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tbl_test = Document.Data.Tables['data source scott']
calc_col = tbl_test.Columns.Item['Job Job']
calc_col.Properties.SetProperty('Expression','[JOB]')
```

The above code works for me. Is it what you tried to do ?
The question is why did you use

```
'calc_col.As<CalculatedColumn>()'
```

?

Comment: That worked like a charm! I just didn't realize that I could access the Expression property without the object being a 'CalculatedColumn' since tbl_test.Columns.Item[] returns a DataColumn. I was basically trying to typecast using As<CalculatedColumn> . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I first try to update an existing calculation.
If that fails I try to delete the column 1st (if it's frozen), then I add a new column with the calculation.

The basic of the replace is:
lc_myField = ldt_tbl.Columns['Column Name'].AsCalculatedColumn
lc_myField.Expression = ls_CalcExpression

The basics of the add are:
ldt_tbl.Columns.AddCalculatedColumn('Column Name', ls_CalcExpression)

where the ldt_tbl is the data table, and ls_calcExpression contains your expression.

Comment: I tried the replace section of the code and it give me and error that the object does not contain an 'Expression' property

Comment: Luis, Can you post what you did, not just the code section, but the complete code?